# display original list after shuffle function

Tags: javascript

See my code snipped
I've an html list and function window.onload = shuffleNodes; that display automatically a shuffle list.
How to add a button function to display the original list order?
Thank you very much!!!

```js
var list = document.getElementById("something"),
button = document.getElementById("shuffle");
function shuffle(items)
{
    var cached = items.slice(0), temp, i = cached.length, rand;
    while(--i)
    {
        rand = Math.floor(i * Math.random());
        temp = cached[rand];
        cached[rand] = cached[i];
        cached[i] = temp;
    }
    return cached;
}
function shuffleNodes()
{
    var nodes = list.children, i = 0;
    nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
    nodes = shuffle(nodes);
    while(i < nodes.length)

    {
        list.appendChild(nodes[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
window.onload = shuffleNodes;
```

```html
<dl id="something">
    <dd>one</dd>
    <dd>two</dd>
    <dd>three</dd>
    <dd>four</dd>
    <dd>five</dd>
    <dd>six</dd>
    <dd>seven</dd>
    <dd>eight</dd>
    <dd>nine</dd>
    <dd>ten</dd>
</dl>
<hr>
<button onclick="myFunction()">ORDINATE LIST</button>
```

Comment: just store a copy of `nodes` before shuffling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short trick would be to store the `innerHTML` of element before shuffling, and revert to that HTML upon clicking the button.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("something"),
  button = document.getElementById("shuffle");
let original = list.innerHTML;

function shuffle(items) {
  var cached = items.slice(0),
    temp, i = cached.length,
    rand;
  while (--i) {
    rand = Math.floor(i * Math.random());
    temp = cached[rand];
    cached[rand] = cached[i];
    cached[i] = temp;
  }
  return cached;
}

function myFunction(){
  list.innerHTML = original;
}


function shuffleNodes() {
  var nodes = list.children,
    i = 0;
  nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
  nodes = shuffle(nodes);
  while (i < nodes.length){
    list.appendChild(nodes[i]);
    ++i;
  }
}
window.onload = shuffleNodes;
```

```html
<dl id="something">
  <dd>one</dd>
  <dd>two</dd>
  <dd>three</dd>
  <dd>four</dd>
  <dd>five</dd>
  <dd>six</dd>
  <dd>seven</dd>
  <dd>eight</dd>
  <dd>nine</dd>
  <dd>ten</dd>
</dl>
<hr>
<button onclick="myFunction()">ORDINATE LIST</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest storing a list of the nodes in an `orderedNodes` array, then shuffling before we display initially.

We can then display the ordered list easily again, or shuffle it again, using either of the two buttons.

```js
const orderedNodes = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];

function shuffle(items) {
    var cached = items.slice(0), temp, i = cached.length, rand;
    while(--i) {
        rand = Math.floor(i * Math.random());
        temp = cached[rand];
        cached[rand] = cached[i];
        cached[i] = temp;
    }
    return cached;
}

function displayShuffled() {
    displayNodes(shuffle(orderedNodes));
}

function displayOrdered() {
    displayNodes(orderedNodes)
}

function displayNodes(nodes) {
    clearNodes();
    nodes.forEach(displayNode);
}

function clearNodes() {
    const list = document.getElementById("something");
    list.innerHTML = '';
}

function displayNode(nodeText) {
    const list = document.getElementById("something");
    const el = document.createElement("dd");
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nodeText));   
    list.appendChild(el);
}

window.onload = displayShuffled;
```

```html
<dl id="something">
</dl>
<hr>
<button onclick="displayOrdered()">Order List</button>
<button onclick="displayShuffled()">Shuffle List</button>
```